# Flutter where and firstwhere methods is calls null with data from provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

**First is is getting null in HomeScreen**

Here is the code:

```
final providedList = Provider.of<List<category.List>>(
  context,
);

appbarColor = providedList
    .firstWhere(
      (element) => element.name == currentListName,
     orElse: () => providedList.first,
    )
    .color;
```

Here is the error

> The method 'firstWhere' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: firstWhere(Closure: (List) => bool, orElse: Closure: () => List)

**then HomeBody**

Here is the code:

```
List<Todo> todos = context.watch<List<Todo>>()
        .where((e) =>
            e.category == widget.selectedCategory && e.isCompleted == false)
        .toList() ??
    [];
```

Here is the error

> The method 'where' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: where(Closure: (Todo) => bool)
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> HomeBody

and each error code prints twice

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `providedList` is equal to null. You need to get a properly initialized value from the provider, then call the methods `.firstWhere` and `.where`.

in provider class

```
List<Todo> todos = [];
```

in other place

```
 List<Todo> readTodoFromProvider = Provider.of<Todo>(context,listen: false).todos;
 
 var result =  readTodoFromProvider.where((e) =>e.category == widget.selectedCategory && e.isCompleted == false).toList();
```

To make the `Provider` work, you need to add it Providers are above MyApp, for example

```
//lib/main.dart

void main() {
  runApp(

    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Todo()),
      ],


      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```